# how to sign .apk with existing jks file using jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins

Here is my current configuration.

I have already downloaded the plugin 'Android Signing Plugin'. I just don't know what to put in there since i already have a generated key.

I can't create a new one because i already published the application in playstore.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What i did was write a build variant and signed configs in gradle like this

```
android {


    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig{
            storeFile file("*****");
            storePassword ("****");
            keyAlias "*****";
            keyPassword "****"
        }
```

and in build types

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
    debug{
        debuggable true
    }
```

now my jenkis generate 2 apk files 1 debug and 1 signed.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/VaS3jN3.png]

[More info here.](https://youtu.be/yGK8DCKB-H0)

Let me know if you have a better answer. Thanks.